# How does the landing gear damp vibrations?

Tags: landing, landing-gear

How does a landing gear on an aircraft reduce the vibrations transferred to the airplane structure, while landing?

Comment: suspension, just like in your car only more heavy duty.

Comment: make that an answer, @ratchetfreak

Comment: The gear extends on what is effectively a large shock absorber which has a piston moving in a cylinder of hydraulic fluid and nitrogen.

Answer (score 4):

By having a spring element and a damping element - some small planes use use leaf or tubular legs bending to act as springs, other use rubber bungy cords, others use, like bigger aircraft commonly do, a gas strut damped by liquid viscosity. The damping in the puddle jumpers is the scrub of the tyres moving laterally on the runway as the suspension moves up and down. Shimmy damping in the nose gears can be either by elements providing viscous damping or coulomb/friction damping.

Comment: don't forget to add the effect of pneumatic tires. In [some aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaflieg_Braunschweig_SB-7_Nimbus) this is the only thing which dampens the shocks during landing and taxiing on rough terrain.

Comment: absolutely! Thanks